# Delete emails from specific senders after 30 days using Shortcuts

Tags: mail.app, email, shortcuts-app

I have some senders (like Amazon) whose emails lose relevance after 30 days for me. I am trying to write a Shortcuts that can search for emails from those senders and delete them after 30 days. I intend to run the Shortcut as an automation every day.

When I open the Shortcuts app on macOS (Sonoma 14.2.1) I see an action 'Find Message'. But I am not able to enter the email ID manually in the action.

[image]

When I open the Shortcuts app on iPhone (iOS 17.2.1) I see action 'Search in Mail'. It allows me to search on a text and ends up opening Apple Mail on iPhone

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the regular Mail Rules.

[image]

If all conditions are met:
From contains amazon
Date received is greater than 30 days.

Delete messages.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. How often/when are these rules evaluated?

Comment: As far as I know, every time new mail comes in, it runs all rules; or you can apply to a selection on the right click menu.